# Extend an axis limit to -1 when that axis is logarithmic in R

Tags: r, plot, logarithm

I am doing the following:

```
x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = x ^ 2
plot(x, y, log="y")
```

What I want is that the graph also show me the scatter point at (x, y)=(0, 0).

I know that `log(0) = -Inf`. This will be the case when I am doing `log(x)` but here I am not doing `log(x)`. Rather, I am just changing the scale of y-axis to be logarithmic. Therefore, I need to know if there is some way for me to display the scatter point (x, y) = (0, 0) as well.

Comment: Replace `y[1]` with `0.1` and plot. Then replace it with `0.0001`, or `0.000000001`, and try again - hopefully this will demonstrate why your original goal can't be achieved - there is an infinite distance between 1 and 0 on a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you are asking is mathematically impossible, because `log(0) = -Inf`. The point (0, 0) cannot be shown on a log-scale plot.

A log-scale is produced by log-transforming the data values and exponentiating the values at the axis ticks. For example, to plot the value 100 in a log-10 scale, you first log-transform 100 to `log10(100) = 2`, and then you transform the corresponding axis tick from 2 to `10^2 = 100`. Thus, to plot the value 0 in a log-scale plot, you still need to calculate `log10(0)`, even if the corresponding axis tick would be `10^-Inf = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to have a non-linear y-axis, and not necessarily a log-scale, then you can follow something like what's below.

```
# transfrom y-values
ny <- sqrt(y) 
# plot the transformed values
plot(x, ny, yaxt='n', ylab = "y")
# label the y-axis 
axis(side = 2, at = ny, labels = y)
```

[image]

Also, if you know what you want to replace log(0) with, then you can do that via `ny`, but I don't advise using log-scale when there is a zero.